# Woocommerce Add prices

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Greatings,

Is there a way for example:

Product 1 price is set to : 50€
Product 2 price is set to : 45€
Product 3 price is set to : 20€

To add BULK price to all products for example if i set to add 50€ more to prices system automaticully changes product prices to

Product 1 price is set to : 100€
Product 2 price is set to : 95€
Product 3 price is set to : 70€

I know how to change products manually or by quick edit but i need this option if i wanna i can disable and prices comes by default and then i enbale prices add for example +50€

Comment: yes, this is possible. question is, if this needs to be applied to all products, or if that feature would need further filtering.. and for the amount, i'd use an ACF options page to have a place in the cms to enter the value..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to add or remove an amount from standard prices at any time, you could add a custom field to WooCommerce's settings pages, then modify the price of your products using the built-in filter.

Here is how I would do it: (this would go in your theme's `functions.php` file)

```
/**
 * Add a new tab to WooCommerce settings pages
**/
function add_wc_settings_tabs( $settings_tabs ) {
    $settings_tabs[ 'modify-price' ] = __( 'Modify Price', 'woocommerce' );

    return $settings_tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'add_my_wc_settings_tabs', 60 );

/**
 * Set up settings fields
**/
function get_my_custom_settings() {
    return array(
        array(
            'title'     => __( 'Amount to add', 'woocommerce' ),
            'desc'      => '<br/>' . __( 'Enter an amount to add to each product price', 'woocommerce' ),
            'id'        => 'price_modification_amount',
            'type'      => 'number',
            'min'       => '0',
            'step'      => '.01',
            'append'    => '€',
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Outputs settings fields on the Modify Price settings tab
**/
function my_custom_settings_page() {
    woocommerce_admin_fields( apply_filters( 'wc_get_settings_modify-price', get_my_custom_settings() );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_modify-price', 'my_custom_settings_page' );

/**
 * Update fields in database when page saved
**/
function update_my_custom_settings() {
    woocommerce_update_options( get_my_custom_settings() );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_modify-price', 'update_my_custom_settings' );
```

Once you've added these functions, you will be able to set an amount in WooCommerce > Settings, under your newly created 'Modify Price' tab.

Finally, to adjust prices based on this amount, add this function, again, to `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Modify price HTML if a modification is set in Settings
**/
function my_custom_price_html( $output, $product ) {
    $adjustment = get_option('price_modification_amount');

    if ( $adjustment ) {
        $output = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) + $adjustment;
    }
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_custom_price_html', 30, 2 );

/**
 * Update price in cart if modification set in Settings
**/
function modify_cart_item_price( $cart_item ) {
    $adjustment = get_option('price_modification_amount');

    if ( $adjustment ) {
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price() + $adjustment;
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price );
        $cart_item['my_price'] = $price;
    }
    return $cart_item;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'modify_cart_item_price', 30, 1 );

/**
 * Set correct price when reading cart from session
**/
function get_my_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['my_price'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['my_price'] );
    }
    return $cart_item;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'get_my_cart_item_from_session', 30, 3 );
```